# JSP: jsp page not found in the expected path

Tags: eclipse, jsp

what is the issue here and how can I solve it?

**summary.jsp**

[image]

**Eclipse Problems Log**

```
Fragment "pageTemplates/summary/personal_info.jsp" was not found at expected path /cms-web/WebContent/WEB-INF/pages/provider/enrollment/steps/pageTemplates/pageTemplates/summary/personal_info.jsp 
Fragment "pageTemplates/summary/practice_info.jsp" was not found at expected path /cms-web/WebContent/WEB-INF/pages/provider/enrollment/steps/pageTemplates/pageTemplates/summary/practice_info.jsp summary.jsp
```

Comment: Where are the files really that you're trying to include?  Where's the JSP?  List their paths in the workspace (right-click->copy qualified name).